# tomcat 6 configuration problem?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, war, web.xml

hello
if uploaded my war file to webapps and restarted tomcat
it deployed my file but its not reachable from "outside"
is there sth wrong with the config:

```
cat ./TEST/WEB-INF/web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-    app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TEST</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Test</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


./TEST/WEB-INF/classes:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat6 tomcat6 4096 Dec 28 12:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 tomcat6 tomcat6 4096 Dec 28 12:37 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat6 tomcat6 2329 Dec 28  2010 Test.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat6 tomcat6 2380 Dec 28  2010 Test.java
```

but if i call xxx.com/test i got 404
where is my fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:
host/TEST/test

Host/{appContext}/{servletContext}